# regex and os.walk

Tags: python, regex, directory, os.walk

I'm pretty new to python but learning fast.  I'm trying to use regex with os.walk to ignore directories that I don't want processed.  I understand that you must modify the dirs in place and not create a new list.  I have tried it both ways though.  I don't get any errors but it still traverses all the directory's.  Exluding full dir names works fine. I am trying to remove all directories with 'EXP' or '-' or '3.2' in the name. Here is an example I want to ignore 
3.2.2.150-20150424.195805_EXP_manuMain_outOfMemFix

This is what I have:

```
def runtest(filepath_udu: object) -> object:   
    k = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath_udu, topdown=True):
        dirs[:] = [item for item in dirs 
                   if item not in ('1node','local','remote')]
        dirs[:] = [dir for dir in dirs 
                   if re.search(r'\bEXP\b', dir) not in dirs \
                   or re.search(r'\b3.2\b', dir) not in dirs \
                   or re.search(r'\w+(?:- \w+)+', dir) not in dirs]
    for file in files:
        do something...
```

What am i doing wrong that my 2nd dirs[:] is being ignored?  Thanks

Comment: `if re.search(r'\bEXP\b', dir) not in dirs` checks if the word "EXP" is not in the list of `dirs`. Most of the time, it is not. What you want is `if not re.search(r'\bEXP\b', dir)` (sic). Same with the other two conditions, and change 'or' to 'and'.

Comment: As a side note, you don’t need backslash continuations in an expression that’s inside parens, brackets, or braces; those are automatically continued.

Comment: @DYZ No, the `walk` iterator explicitly looks at the changes you made. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for details, but the OP is doing that part exactly right: "When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again."

Comment: To clarify a little bit, I am traversing directories of products collecting performance data from firmware builds to keep track of how performance changes.  I want to ignore experimental fixes, bug fixes, CFI's, etc and all those have EXP or '-' in the name.  I also don't want older firmware like 3.2. Firmware that I want are in a X.X.X.xxx numerical format, the last numbers don't always have 3 digits--it can be 1,2,or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not being ignored, it’s just that your condition is always true, so you aren’t filtering anything out.

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is going to return a match object if something is found, or `None` if not. Either way, that’s not going to be an element of `dirs`, because `dirs` is just a list of strings. So all of your tests are always true.

Instead of checking that the search is not in `dirs`, just check that it’s not truthy. (A match object is always truthy, and `None` is always falsey.)

Also, after you fix that, I’m pretty sure you wanted to keep the values where *all* of the tests fail—but you’re using `or` instead of `and`, which means you’re keeping the values where *any* of the tests fail.

So:

```
dirs[:] = [dir for dir in dirs
           if not re.search(r'\bEXP\b', dir)
           and not re.search(r'\b3.2\b', dir) 
           and not re.search(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+', dir)]
```

Or, if it’s easier to understand the other way round—instead of keep all values where all the tests fail, keep all values where none of the tests is true:

```
dirs[:] = [dir for dir in dirs if not (
           re.search(r'\bEXP\b', dir) or
           re.search(r'\b3.2\b', dir) or
           re.search(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+', dir))]
```

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much.  I did have to make a minor change though.  using r\bEXP\b wasn't working.  I changed it to a regex (r'\w+(?:EXP\w+)+' and this worked, although a co-worker indicated that if I remove the \b that would have worked to.

Comment: @DB_65 I didn't test your regexes at all; I just assumed they did what you wanted, and you just needed to know how to apply them properly. Glad to know you got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `os.walk`, you can avoid the overhead of dealing with list manipulations by recursively traversing the sub-directories on your own with `os.scandir` after excluding those that match your exclusion criteria:

```
def runtest(filepath_udu: object) -> object:
    for entry in os.scandir(filepath_udu):
        if entry.is_dir() and entry.name not in ('1node', 'local', 'remote') and not re.search(r'\bEXP\b', entry.name) and not re.search(r'\b3.2\b', entry.name) and not re.search(r'\w+(?:- \w+)+', entry.name):
            runtest(entry.path)
        else:
            do something ...
```

Comment: What overhead? The cost of all of those extra `stat` syscalls (from calling `isdir` on every file) is going to be much, much higher than the savings of avoiding a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer with the much more efficent `os.scandir` instead, which is what `os.walk` uses internally. The OP can refer to [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) for details.